# FileNotFound Exception but file is there

Tags: c#, image, file

not much to explain as I have no logical explaination as to why this is not working :s
[image]

Just to confirm, It is a 'jpeg' file extention, the name is correct and I don't see any other issue with why it would not work be found.

Comment: All the files i have been using have been in 'read only' folders, I can not only not change from 'read only' but I can wrote and create images in these folders, so thats not the issue(And it says file not found, its not a permission problem)

Comment: *Please* don't just include screenshots in future. You've got the code as text - why are you preventing us from copying and pasting it in our answers?

Comment: poor quality screenshot, can't check what file name match =D

Comment: Do you try to open image which is a product of `SaveSkypeAvatarToDisk`?

Comment: Which operating system are you using, by the way? If this is a Mac hosting a Windows drive or something, you might want to try using `/` instead of `\`...

Comment: your code *seems* to show saving as ".jpg", but trying to load ".jpeg" Then on the right, there is a file with same name but extension of ".wls" (or something, hard to tell in a screenshot)....

Comment: @baldric: I think it's showing the file *without* the file extension at all. It's hard to tell though...

Comment: oops, right you are.... As always :/

Comment: Sorry guys, simple mistake and i feel stupid, thanks for the help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're saving it to a filename ending with "jpg" and then *loading* from a filename ending with "jpeg". Assuming you're trying to load the file you've just saved, that's the problem.

(I'd copy the code to point out the lines in question, but you only included it as an image...)

I'd strongly suggest constructing the filename *once*, and using that variable twice:

```
// I prefer using Path.Combine over string concatenation, but both will work.
// You might want to change "Identitys" to "Identities" though :)
string file = Path.Combine(@"C:\", "SimpleSkype", "Identitys", dd + ".jpg");
SaveSkypeAvatarToDisk(u.Handle, file);
using (Image image = Image.FromFile(file))
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: It saves as a '.JPEG' so i loaded it as a '.JPEG'
I have tired loading it as '.JPG' aswell. No luck

Comment: @Cacoon: Look at the code you posted. You're *not* saving it as ".jpeg", you're saving it as ".jpg". If you're saying that `SaveSkypeAvatarToDisk` automatically *adds* a `.jpeg` extension, then you should end up with a filename of "foo.jpg.jpeg". Check that.

Comment: Apologies, did not know that. Voted up and chosen.